# How to make python go through specific part of for loop go first?

Tags: python, for-loop, boolean, conditional-statements, turtle-graphics

Say we got a list (it has more lists within this list, but ive included one just for demonstration purposes):

```
list = [
    ['X', ['House A', 'Location 4', 'Right'],
          ['House D', 'Location 3', 'Left'],
          ['House C', 'Location 2', 'Right']]
```

And I made a function like this:

```
def example(lists):
    for element in lists:
       if element[0] == 'House A':
            if element[1] == 'Location 4':
                if element[2]  == 'Right':
                    direction = 0
                    house1(loc4, direction)
                elif element[2] == 'Left':
                    direction = 180
                    house1(loc4, direction)
    if element[0] == 'X':
             graffiti()
```

How can I make it so that if everything is true after the for-loop (I may have not done the for loop correctly in this example but it is correct in the proper version of my code), it draws the graffiti(). (Doing turtle graphics)

Comment: For writing your code blocks, use 4 spaces indentation instead of backticks, backticks are for **inline** code only

Comment: There's also a "code format" button and a live preview...

Comment: "but it is correct in the proper version of my code". Why don't you show us the proper version then?

Comment: And what exactly you mean by 'everything is true after for loop'? What is 'everything'?

Comment: @Jarek.D Didnt show proper version as it for an assignment and didnt want to get any plaigarism if this came up in it.

Comment: @Jarek.D I meant everything after if element[0] == 'House A' and before if element[0] == 'X'. However i have figured the answer to the question myself. I was meant to put lists[0] == 'X' to refer to the 'X'.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test this code:

```
direction_map = {'Right': 0, 'Left': 180}
def example(lists):
    for element in lists:
        if element[0] == 'House A' and element[1] == 'Location 4':
            house1(loc4, direction_map[element[2]])
    if list(element for element in lists if (element[0] == 'House A' 
            and element[1] == 'Location 4')) and (element[2] in direction_map)):
        ....
    if element[0] == 'X':
         graffiti()
```

but from what I understood from what you posted maybe `any` method is what you are looking for.